# Another visual puzzle

Tags: visual, steganography

Hmmz, it seems that I need to add 30 characters here, even though an image says more than a thousand words...
[image: The puzzle]
When you think you have solved it, please read this hint:

> What kind of cookies do I like?

Comment: This is a not-so-visual puzzle

Comment: Nice one. +1. It would be a tiny bit better with a one-pixel-black-border to ensure one doesn't see "just a blank" on some systems and jumps over the puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colors are slight off, filling it in it makes:

> I Like Cookies

then filling it in with my old ass paint program I get:

> [image: morse image]

which is decoded in morse to

> chocolate

Comment: Where/how is the code hidden? I can't find it at all

Comment: The way I used to obtain the code is to download the image, and open it with paint (I used version 5.1, but I dont think it makes any diffrence). Copy-paste wont do any good :)

Comment: That's exactly what I did to find the initial message. There doesn't seem to be anything else unfilled afterwards, though

Comment: Hmm.. odd, I think it has to do with the image being transparent. The paint version I used, can't handle transparency, so instead of showing the picture + transparency layer, it showed the percentage of transparency used in the picture, as color.

Comment: Similar to @LogicianWithAHat I can download and fill to get the message, but not the morse code. (Using IrfanView.)

Answer (score 0):

> The message in the image says "I like cookies" Although the image appears completely blank opening it with an image editor and using the fuzzy select tool reveals the words.

Comment: Almost there. I want to include a hint in spoiler tag but that does not work here. Edited OP.

Answer (score 0):

> I like cookies
> [image: me too]

Solved by:

> Filling in the image- there's an off-white section that provides the message